# defaultDocuments setting not getting created via the Bicep template

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I have a bicep template that creates the AppService Plan and the WebApp. I'm playing around with the SiteConfig settings to setup Default Documents, I've tried adding that via Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01 as well as via Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' but haven't had any luck. I've tried searching to see if there is something I am missing when setting up defaultDocuments but couldn't find anything. Does anyone here know why my template isn't setting defaultdocuments? I am able to see them when I create the App Service via Visual studio but I need to do it via bicep. After creating the AppService via VS, I also looked at the template to make sure I was doing it correctly and I dont see any differences.

```
@description('Web app name.')
@minLength(2)
param appServiceName string = 'QSCloudDashboard' // Generate unique String for web app name

@description('Describes plan\'s pricing tier and instance size. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/')
@allowed([
  'F1'
  'D1'
  'B1'
  'B2'
  'B3'
  'S1'
  'S2'
  'S3'
  'P1'
  'P2'
  'P3'
  'P4'
])
param sku string = 'B2' // The SKU of App Service Plan

param location string = resourceGroup().location // Location for all resources

@description('The language stack of the app.')
@allowed([
  '.net'
  'php'
  'node'
  'html'
])
param language string = '.net'

var configReference = {
  '.net': {
    comments: '.Net app. No additional configuration needed.'
  }
  html: {
    comments: 'HTML app. No additional configuration needed.'
  }
  php: {
    phpVersion: '7.4'
  }
}

var appServicePlanName = toLower('${appServiceName}-AppServicePlan')


resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-06-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
}

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: appServiceName
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    siteConfig: union(configReference[language],{
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
      //netFrameworkVersion:'dotnet'
      //numberOfWorkers: 1
    //   defaultDocuments: [
    //     'Default.htm'
    //     'Default.html'
    //     'Default.asp'
    //     'index.htm'
    //     'index.html'
    //     'iisstart.htm'
    //     'default.aspx'
    //     'index.php'
    //     'hostingstart.html'
    // ]
      scmMinTlsVersion: '1.2'
      ftpsState: 'AllAllowed'
      acrUseManagedIdentityCreds: false
      alwaysOn: false
      http20Enabled: false
      functionAppScaleLimit: 0
      minimumElasticInstanceCount: 0
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '6.9.1'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'InstrumentationKey=1caef12c-6950-4ffb-9edf-d552e0b84643;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/'
        }
        {
          name: 'ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~2'
        }
        {
          name: 'DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~3'
        }
      ]
    })
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    reserved: false
    isXenon: false
    hyperV: false
    httpsOnly: true
    scmSiteAlsoStopped: false
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    clientCertEnabled: false
    clientCertMode: 'Required'
    hostNamesDisabled: false
    containerSize: 0
    dailyMemoryTimeQuota: 0
    redundancyMode: 'None'
  }
}

resource appService_name_web 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
   parent: appService
   name: 'web'
   location: 'East US'
   properties: {
     numberOfWorkers: 1
     defaultDocuments: [
      'Default.htm'
      'Default.html'
      'Default.asp'
      'index.htm'
      'index.html'
      'iisstart.htm'
      'default.aspx'
      'index.php'
      'hostingstart.html'
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting defaultDocuments in your appService_name_web *should* work, but I believe your appService had some funky config inside of it. A few small changes, we'll simplify appService a bit and try moving your config to your appService_name_web section.

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: appServiceName
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: true
      defaultDocuments: []
    }
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    clientCertEnabled: false
  }
}
```

Then in your config:

```
resource appService_name_web 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
   parent: appService
   name: 'web'
   properties: {
     numberOfWorkers: 1
     defaultDocuments: [
      'Default.htm'
      'Default.html'
      'Default.asp'
      'index.htm'
      'index.html'
      'iisstart.htm'
      'default.aspx'
      'index.php'
      'hostingstart.html'
    ]
    minTlsVersion: '1.2'
    linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
    scmMinTlsVersion: '1.2'
    ftpsState: 'AllAllowed'
    acrUseManagedIdentityCreds: false
    http20Enabled: false
    functionAppScaleLimit: 0
    minimumElasticInstanceCount: 0
  }
}
```

You can break out a new appSettings section as well if you'd like:

```
resource appService_name_web_appSettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
   parent: appService
   name: 'appsettings'
   properties: {
     appSettings: {
       'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION': '6.9.1'
       'APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING': 'InstrumentationKey=1caef12c-6950-4ffb-9edf-d552e0b84643;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/'
       'ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION': '~2'
       'DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION': '~3'
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation. This helped! However, i've noticed that if I set the framework version using the linuxFxVersion element, I don't get the "defaultDocuments" but the Stack under General Settings gets set correctly,  but if i set the framework version using the netFrameworkVersion element, I get the "defaultDocuments" but the Stack under General Settings doesn't get set.

Comment: I generally leave linuxFxVersion: '' for most of our stuff. It is always fun navigating all the settings for this. 1 thing that helps a lot for me is using visual studio code and downloading the bicep extension. It has really good intellisense. It will help with api versions, what properties they can use, what properties can be used with each other, etc. Microsoft API docs with the description. Another useful tool is using the bicep what-if to do basically a preview of the deployment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell%2CCLI